# Weird Log Messages in D-Link Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, troubleshooting

I bought a D-Link router three years ago and have been getting these log messages ever since:
[image: Log Messages on D-Link router]
I recently upgraded the firmware to the latest, hoping these would go away, but they are still there. Can you explain these messages?

Comment: There's nothing weird going on: every computer connected to the internet will be receiving such packets. The messages may be a little on the dramatic side, though. If you don't like being probed, just pull the plug.

Comment: I have other routers that don't get the Port Scan Attack or Per-Source ACK Flood messages. So, if you don't have an explanation, refrain from making these comments.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, most home routers do not log events like this as the average consumer will get spooked by them. Most any device sitting directly on the internet will be hit with port scans and such all day long. If you are worried it is the router then you can always try plugging a computer directly into your WAN (i.e. cable or DSL modem) connection and run Wireshark. I'm sure that it won't take long to see just how much traffic your home router drops.

The other potential scenario is that your other router was not blocking the port scans. To find out, you can run Wireshark from a device that is connected to your LAN. If the IPs from the logs show inside your LAN up then I guess your router needs replaced... And look! you have one that will stop that from happening already!